# Rally Tool - API

Tags: rally

We have used QC tool till now, but from now we will start using Rally tool.

As QC is system of testing results, we used to extract data from it using a macro that is designed based on API's.

Now time has come to work on Rally and design such tool. Could anybody help me understand how to connect Rally and extract data in excel format using any programming language(especially vb script). My first interest is to find out whether Rally has any API's like QC used to have, for connecting and extracting data from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# This Ruby script will print out the names of all Workspaces the user has access to.
# More API info:  https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby
# Invoke with 3 arguments:  'https://rally1.rallydev.com'  'username@domain.com'  'MyPassword'

require 'rally_api'

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(
        :base_url   => ARGV[0].end_with?('/slm') ? "#{ARGV[0]}" : "#{ARGV[0]}/slm",
        :username   => "#{ARGV[1]}",
        :password   => "#{ARGV[2]}",
        :version    => 'v2.0')

sub = @rally.find(RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new(
        :type           => :subscription,
        :query_string   => '(ObjectID > 0)',
        :fetch          => true))

sub.first[:Workspaces].each_with_index do |w,i|
    puts "Workspace #{i+1} - #{w}"
end 

#[the end]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Rally Connector for Excel if it has to be Excel-based.  Alternatively, you can access the Rally Web Services API (docs here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/), but haven't been able to solve it in Excel. We connect read-only with Power Query and Power BI, but you can also create through it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).